# Throw exception when access image from App.xaml.cs

Tags: wpf, app.xaml

First, try this.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="80" Width="100" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Image x:Name="image"/>
</Window>
```

and

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static  BitmapImage okImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://Application:,,,/ok.png"));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        image.Source = okImage;
    }
}
```

REMEMBER put any image named ok.png to the project directory. This runs well and shows an image in the window.

Now try to move `public static  BitmapImage okImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://Application:,,,/ok.png"));` to App.xaml.cs.

Run again, we get TypeInitializationException. Why?

I know I can define okImage in MainWindow.xaml.cs, but if I insist it must be defined and initilized in App.xaml.cs, how should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Usually `TypeInitializationException` iteslf is not very helpful - always check it's `InnerException` property.
In your case, it says "Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.", which is much more helpful.
It tells that the problem isn't image itself, it's `Uri` constructor which throws exception.

But why it succeeds in `MainWindow.xaml.cs` and fails in `App.xaml.cs`?

It's all about `UriParser` schemes. `UriParser` defines way of parsing some parts of `Uri` and is involved in `Uri` object initialization. When your `MainWindow` object is accessed for the first time, it's static constructor is called and your image is created. At this moment, your application has already registered a `UriParser` for `pack://` scheme, and `Uri` parser succeeds. But when you try to do the same thing in `Application.xaml.cs`, custom `UriParser` for `pack://` scheme is not yet registered, and default one fails.

Solution:

Do not instantiate your images in `Application` static constructor. You may still keep fields or properties and make them static if you want, but move all your image initialization code to `OnStartup()`:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static BitmapImage okImage;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        okImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ok.png"));
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your explaination is helpful. Nontheless can not I manually load pack scheme parser? Because I can not use the readonly keyword on okImage.